# How to fix layout issue ? How my app appear same on different devices

Tags: android

I am using Android 2.3.3 . i develop a very small android app that is an android calculator it works perfect but when i rotate screen and it comes to landscape my input screen doesn't show . i am using kotlin as a programming language .[this is what appears on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO5F4.jpg)

[in original it look like this .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTnPK.jpg)

this is the xml of my layout. Help me to solve this issue.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/DpScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:paddingTop="10pt"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30pt" />

<TableLayout
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginBottom="1pt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/B1"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="Ac"
            android:text="AC"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:id="@+id/B2"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="bNumberClick"
            android:text="+/-"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/B3"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="Bpercent"
            android:text="%"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Bmul"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/lightorange"
            android:onClick="OpBtn"
            android:text="*"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginBottom="1pt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:id="@+id/B5"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="bNumberClick"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:id="@+id/B6"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="bNumberClick"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:id="@+id/B7"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="bNumberClick"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Bdiv"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/lightorange"
            android:onClick="OpBtn"
            android:text="/"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginBottom="1pt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:id="@+id/B9"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="bNumberClick"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:id="@+id/B10"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="bNumberClick"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:id="@+id/B11"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="bNumberClick"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Bsum"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/lightorange"
            android:onClick="OpBtn"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginBottom="1pt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:id="@+id/B13"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="bNumberClick"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:id="@+id/B14"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="bNumberClick"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
            android:id="@+id/B15"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/hashwhite"
            android:onClick="bNumberClick"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Bsub"
            android:layout_width="30pt"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/lightorange"
            android:onClick="OpBtn"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
        android:id="@+id/B17"
        android:layout_width="60pt"
        android:layout_height="30pt"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/hashwhite"
        android:onClick="bNumberClick"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginRight="1pt"
        android:id="@+id/B18"
        android:layout_width="31pt"
        android:layout_height="30pt"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/hashwhite"
        android:onClick="bNumberClick"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Beql"
        android:layout_width="24pt"
        android:layout_height="30pt"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/lightorange"
        android:onClick="BuEqual"
        android:text="="
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your xml layout file

Comment: yes i add my xml layout please check this

Comment: check my ans @Qudsia

Comment: @NileshRathod i check your answer but can i paste it before layout start?

Comment: no just add your controls in linear layout

Comment: sure why not...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a relative layout as the root layout. If you do so you can set the table layout to be drawn below the edit text all the time. Also try to avoid using fixed width and heights because they don`t draw nicely on different devices. Take a look at "weight" attribute.